# What Azure hosting would automatically scale a .NET Core Web API service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling, azure-webapps

I am building an ASP.NET Web API service that receives orders from restaurants.
At certain times it will be busy, thousands of times more busy than at other times.

I haven't begun developing this yet but I was wondering what Azure services are appropriate to host the service such that it automatically scales when necessary without me worrying about its performance and hosting costs are minimised?

Comment: Easiest would probably be App Service - some of the tiers offer autoscaling.

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic, as it's very broad, opinion-soliciting, and asking for service recommendations. The docs describe all scale options for each service, including ones that have ability to auto-scale. But there's just no way to guess which services you'll need, especially considering we don't know anything about how complex your app is, what database you use, whether there are specific api's, on and on...

Answer (score 3):

You can create Azure Functions to handle this and auto scale or use an Azure App Service and set it up to auto scale.

Azure functions can be setup to be triggered on HTTP events. These can be configured to scale to multiple instances to handle heavier load. You will need multiple Azure Functions to handle multiple API endpoints.

An azure app service will be will have an app service plan which can be configured to scale horizontally or vertically when the traffic load increases. An app service will be more like a traditional api instead of a small piece of an API like an Azure Function.